# Edit Global array in Express

Tags: node.js, express

I want to change one item from array from app locals variable and i am not sure how to do this

Here is what i have set as global

```
app.locals.products=[{name: 'a',url: '/a' },
    {name: 'b',url: '/b' },
    {name: 'c',url: '/c' },...
```

I want to edit them and set active product from routes and do something like this

```
    products:[{name: 'a',url: '/a' active:true}],
```

But when i do this it will remove all the other items and set only the product the one i wrote. Is there a way to edit just the one i need and leave all the rest unchanged?

Comment: you need to find index of product ... products[index].active = true

Comment: @David can you give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the array find function to find a specific item in the products array and edit it.

```
function setActive(name) {

  var element = products.find(function(product) {
    return product.name === name;
  });

  if (element) {
    element.active = true;
  }
}
```

This function takes the `name` variable, checks if it exists in the `product` array and sets it to active. You might want to throw an exception if it doesn't.

Usage:

```
setActive('a');
```

Comment: i get error 500... i used it in routes inside router get.. Could this be because i have spaces?

Comment: here is the global array
``app.locals.products=[{name: 'Window & residential door systems',url: '/en/products/window-residential-door-systems' },
        {name: 'Sliding systems',url: '/en/product/sliding_system' },
        {name: 'Shutter systems',url: '/en/product/shutter_system' },
        {name: 'Sheets',url: '/en/product/sheets' },
        {name: 'Building profiles & systems',url: '/en/product/profiles&systems' }];``

Comment: and this is the routes``var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var url = req.originalUrl;
  function setActive(name) {
  var element = products.find(function(product) {
    return product.name === name;
  });
  if (element) {
    element.active = true;
  }}
  setActive('Window & residential door system');
  res.render('index', {
      title: 'The premium brand',
      pageurl: url,
      welcome: true
     });
});
module.exports = router;
``

Comment: Did you put the function definition inside the router.get function? it should be outside of it, of course, and only the setActive call should be inside .. the spaces should be no problem

Comment: i still get error 500... i even try to set the function on app.js and only call setActive on routes.get but still nothing...

Comment: ReferenceError: products is not defined

Comment: ok i made some changes i placed the function on app.js and changed the `element = products.find`` to ''element = app.locals.products.find'' and it worked ! but the problem is when i place the setActive on routes i dont know how to import the function from app.js can you help ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: when i use everything on appjs it works great (both function and setActive)
if however i place them on routes they cant find the products

Comment: Ok i have found what  was the problem, i had to request the locals variable first and also place all the code including the setActive outside from the render...
  ``function setActive(name) {var element = req.app.locals.products.find(function(product) {return product.name === name;});
      if (element) {element.active = true;}}
      setActive('a');``
thanks for the help!